# svg how to add a border on a svg symbol?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm using a big svg that contains flags of countries, eg

```
<symbol viewBox="0 0 640 480" id="flag-be">
   <g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="1pt">
      <path d="M0 0h213.34v480H0z" />
      <path fill="#ffd90c" d="M213.34 0h213.33v480H213.33z" />
      <path fill="#f31830" d="M426.67 0h213.34v480H426.66z" />
   </g>
</symbol>
```

It works great and I can simply svg use #flag-be and voila, got a my flag.

```
<svg class="icon flag-be"><use href="#flag-be"></use></svg>
```

However, I'd like to add a border around the flags (because some that have a lot of white [looks strange](https://techtothepeople.github.io/eucountries/) without it), ideally something that can be set via css only

It works fine when I have each flag into separate svgs (using border), but I failed to make it work when I use several flags as part of a single svg containers (a graph)

What's the easiest? whould I add a a new element in each symbol for the border? What's the most flexible to style "used" symbols in a svg?

Comment: (feb 2020) Happened to end up here for another search.... On the topic of SVG flags.. There is a *Custom Element/Web Component* solution at https://flagmeister.github.io

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `<svg>` nor `<use>` nor `<g>` elements are *graphical* elements. Trying to set a style altering the graphical appearance on them will only lead to the style being inherited by its children. So, if you set a `stroke` on `<use>`, it will be inherited by all the path elements, and you get a border around *every* flag field.

(A point to remember: Content cloned with a `<use>` element can *inherit* styles, but **they cannot be targeted with CSS selectors**.)

So why does setting a `border` work on  the *outermost* `<svg>` element? Because that element is treated as part of the HTML namespace and rendered as if it was an ordinary `<span>`, while for its children in the SVG namespace the `border` property has no meaning.

In your use case, you need to add a graphical element surrounding the whole flag. Probably at the point of use, like this:

```
<svg ...>
    ...
    <svg class="icon flag-be" width="24" height="16">
        <use href="#flag-be" />
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:1" />
    </svg>
    ...
</svg>
```

Note the inner `<svg>` element. Its purpose is to give a reference to the percentage width and height of the `<rect>`. Otherwise, they would be computed in relation to the *outer* `<svg>`.

Currently, `width` and `height` must be set as attributes on an inner `<svg>` element. [SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/geometry.html) defines them as presentation attributes that can be set with CSS, but some browsers still only allow that on outer `<svg>` elements.

Comment: thanks, I've tried, but my style .icon {width:24px;height:16px} is ignored when it's in a inner svg (despite working fine on the main one. I'm utterly confused on when css rules apply or not to svg elements it seems ;) Would you have an idea?

Comment: The style width and height are not used. If you put the sizes directly to the sub-svg it works `<svg class="icon flag-be" width="24" height="16" >`. If you put the stroke-style in the css and give the rect a class that works. `<rect class="iconborder" />` `.iconborder {fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;width:100%;height:100%;}`

Comment: My error. I should have remenbered that is a new feature in SVG2. Unfortunately, this is one of the cases where I am not able to find good compatibility data.